# Scale HTML page based on browser size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to build a page that has to work on whatever size the browser is and scale down appropriately. I'm using the bootstrap framework at the moment, however I'm not tied to it if theres something better.

The idea is it's a customer satisfaction survey that will be filled out on a tablet PC and it can't scroll etc.

At the moment I have my HTML like:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h1>How are we doing?</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">How was the cleanliness today?</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <center>
                <div class="col-xs-2"><img src="img/5.png" alt="" class="img-responsive"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-2"><img src="img/4.png" alt="" class="img-responsive"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-2"><img src="img/3.png" alt="" class="img-responsive"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-2"><img src="img/2.png" alt="" class="img-responsive"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-2"><img src="img/1.png" alt="" class="img-responsive"></div>
            </center>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This works, but of course, doesn't take the page height etc in to consideration so it will make it scroll. The img-responsive class resizes the images appropriately to the width, but it'd be great if it could take the height in to consideration.

I've tried a range of things such as setting the body height to    `height:100vh;`
But i couldnt make it scale down to fit the page. At the moment it looks like:
[image]

I would like it to look like (obviously not this distorted, bad mspaint job):
[image]

Comment: you are missing `class="img-circle"` EDIT:  is it Bootstrap 3 or 2?

Comment: Bootstrap 3 - why would I want circle image? that just makes the image a circle, no?

Comment: it gives some height and width EDIT: this is assuming you do not have one huge img with different smiley faces on it

Comment: You could try PureCSS. http://purecss.io The `pure-img` class resizes the images automatically, still keeping the resolution.

Comment: Okay - i'll look in to it. However, none of these options keep the page 100% whatever the resolution? There will always be scrolling

Answer (score 0):

Your `<div class="panel-body">` contains 1 child and it is `center` and there for your other `<div class="panel-body">` children become like crappy faces get rid of `center` tag

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h1>How are we doing?</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">How was the cleanliness today?</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
```

> 

```
                <div class="col-xs-2"><img src="img/5.png" alt="" class="img-responsive"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-2"><img src="img/4.png" alt="" class="img-responsive"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-2"><img src="img/3.png" alt="" class="img-responsive"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-2"><img src="img/2.png" alt="" class="img-responsive"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-2"><img src="img/1.png" alt="" class="img-responsive"></div>
```

> 

```
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You should follow example from 
[Bootstrap#Panels](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#panels)
and if you choose to add tags in there be prepared it will act different

EDIT: 
Also look at what is your grid layout it may start .container (fixed-width) or .container-fluid (full-width) 
[Bootstrap#Grid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

Comment: This wont scale the page down though

Comment: about the panel it will because in the panel the contents target is the first child in the `panel body`in this case it is `center` but if `center` is removed then it will definitely work